# GLM Model adressing variables

Tags: r, glm

in my GLM model I tested for not significant variables. One of variable in Geography where values woould be country names. So test showed me that variable GeographyCountryA is significant so I want to keep it but not sure how to properly address it ? below gives an error:

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'GeographyGermany' not
> found

Code:

```
churn_model_rl <- glm(data = train_churn, formula = Exited ~ Age+
                     +NumOfProducts+IsActiveMember+Gender+GeographyGermany,family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

Comment: could you please share `class(train_churn[["GeographyGermany"]]`?

Comment: it's:    character

Comment: To fit  a `glm()` object , independent and dependent variables need to be numeric/integer, for this case consider to convert `GeographyGermany` to a column of zeros and ones

Comment: ok, thank you for the input.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. It's also unclear what you mean by "properly address it"--address what?